# javascript extract id's from two levels of arrays for key value pairs in new object

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm getting a payload back that I need to pull id's from two separate levels within the payload and return it as a single object of key value pairs. I was attempting to do some sort of combination or `ForEach()` and `reduce()` but I couldn't seem to find the right way of doing it. Here is a what the data looks like.

```
{
 orderId:999,
 menuId: 123456,
  questions:[{
    questionId: 123,
    depth: 1,
        answers: [
            { answerId: 999, text: "foo1" },
            { answerId: 888, text: "foo2" }]
  },
  {
    questionId: 654,
    depth: 1,
    answers: [{ answerId: 777, text: "bar" }]
  }]
}
```

What I'm attempting to have as the result

```
{"q_123": ["999", "888"], "q_654": "777"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach with `reduce` will do the job:

```js
const data = {
  orderId: 999,
  menuId: 123456,
  questions: [{
      questionId: 123,
      depth: 1,
      answers: [{
          answerId: 999, 
          text: "foo1"
        }, {
          answerId: 888,
          text: "foo2"
        }
      ]
    }, {
      questionId: 654,
      depth: 1,
      answers: [{
        answerId: 777,
        text: "bar"
      }]
    }
  ]};

const result = data.questions.reduce((all, {
  questionId: id,
  answers
}) => {

  all[`q_${id}`] = answers.map(a => a.answerId);

  return all;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: aww, i was not using reduce properly. thanks, it worked perfect!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `reduce` to achieve this :

```js
const data = {
  orderId: 999, menuId: 123456, questions: [
    {
      questionId: 123,
      depth: 1,
      answers: [
        { answerId: 999, text: "foo1"},
        { answerId: 888, text: "foo2"}
      ]
    },
    {
      questionId: 654,
      depth: 1,
      answers: [ { answerId: 777, text: "bar" }]
    }
  ]
}

const result = data.questions.reduce((acc, {questionId, answers}) => {
  return Object.assign({
    [`q_${questionId}`]: answers.map(
      ({answerId}) => answerId
    )
  }, acc)
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is with simple `JSON parsing`.

```js
var input = {
 orderId:999,
 menuId: 123456,
  questions:[{
    questionId: 123,
    depth: 1,
        answers: [
            { answerId: 999, text: "foo1" },
            { answerId: 888, text: "foo2" }]
  },
  {
    questionId: 654,
    depth: 1,
    answers: [{ answerId: 777, text: "bar" }]
  }]
};

var length = input.questions.length;
var questionsobj = input.questions;
var resultJsonData = {};

for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {   
   var question_id = questionsobj[i].questionId;
   var answersobj = questionsobj[i].answers;
   var len = answersobj.length;
   var arrayObject = [];
   
   for(var k=0; k<len; k++) {
      arrayObject[k] = answersobj[k].answerId;
   }
   resultJsonData["q_" + question_id] = arrayObject;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(resultJsonData));
```